# view progressbar with thread

Tags: c#

I have a project in c# and I want to view progressbar with another form in thread mode, when working with data. 
I want to do this:

MyMessageBox.ShowWaiting("Please wait...");
//Do Anything;
MyMessageBox.HideWaiting();

MyMessageBox is a form with a progressbar in marque style.
Can you help me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class which allows you to execute tasks on background threads and [report progress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) at the same time.

Comment: can you say me how do this work with sample code? MyMessage is a form and I work is MainForm.

Comment: @yaghoobi, the documentation I have linked to contains many examples.